# jQuery Mobile changePage() creats VM

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Ctrl.js:

```
console.log("load Ctrl"); //line number 1

$(document).on('click', '#add-user', function () {
    console.log("click");
    openAddUser();
});

function openAddUser () {
    //do some stuff
    $.mobile.changePage('add.html');
}

$(document).on('pageshow', '#user-add', function () {
   console.log("open user add"); //line number 123
   //do some stuff
}
```

If I press the button #add-user I get the following console.log

```
"load Ctrl"     - Ctrl.js:1
"click"         - Ctrl.js:...
"load Ctrl"     - VM1400:1
"open user add" - Ctrl.js:123
"open user add" - VM1400:123 //Number after VM changes
```

Used jQ-Mobile version: 1.4.5

Also all DOM-Elemente are added multiple times, so i have no controll. If I try to add some Elements by Id (e. g. to ) I'm lucky if the right Element was choosen.

So.. why the vm is created by jq-Mobile and how i can prevent it?
Hope you can help me.

Cheers

€dit1: It only occurs if I use javascript.